# MySQL: High CPU/Load after linux OOM killer hit

Tags: performance, mysql-5.7

We have a single VM running MySQL 5.7.20 with 64GB memory and 4 vCPUs (Xeon E5-2690 v3 @ 2.6GHz). This MySQL node is dedicated to our Atlassian Confluence application so it's not having any other apps access it. This MySQL instance was hit by the linux OOM killer last week and some of the tuning configs weren't committed to the configuration file. After the restart we've been having issues with the instance consuming a lot more CPU than previous. I had a running export of all the variables prior to the restart so I've changed the configs back to what they were before and committed to the config file, but still not seeing a reduction in CPU. The one config I didn't re-enable yet is query caching. I'm not sure query caching isn't related to the performance issue yet, but I'm unsure how to verify. Any suggestions on how to continue troubleshooting or what tuning config changes to make?

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/db
tmpdir=/data/dbtmpdir
socket=/data/db/mysql.sock
user=XXXXXX

max_allowed_packet=512M

character-set-server=utf8
collation-server=utf8_bin
default-storage-engine=INNODB

max_connections=1000
max_user_connections=250
max_connect_errors=9999

innodb_buffer_pool_size=48G
innodb_log_file_size=1536M
transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_open_files=500
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_thread_sleep_delay=10000
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT

log-bin=host1-bin.log
max_binlog_size=250M
binlog_format=row
expire_logs_days=7
server-id=1

table_open_cache=5947
table_definition_cache=1500
open_files_limit=11895
read_rnd_buffer_size=4194304

#The below values only apply to MyISAM tables
#bulk_insert_buffer_size=268435456
#join_buffer_size=4194304
#key_buffer_size=536870912
#read_buffer_size=4194304
#sort_buffer_size=4194304

query_cache_type=off
#query_cache_size=134217728
#query_cache_limit=2097152

thread_cache_size=128

# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/data/db/mysqld.pid

[client]
socket=/data/db/mysql.sock
```

Output of INNODB ENGINE STATUS

```
mysql> SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
  Type: InnoDB
  Name:
Status:
=====================================
2019-05-13 11:54:19 0x7f23cf659700 INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
=====================================
Per second averages calculated from the last 49 seconds
-----------------
BACKGROUND THREAD
-----------------
srv_master_thread loops: 336483 srv_active, 0 srv_shutdown, 44130 srv_idle
srv_master_thread log flush and writes: 380609
----------
SEMAPHORES
----------
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: reservation count 349337
OS WAIT ARRAY INFO: signal count 404712
RW-shared spins 0, rounds 500842, OS waits 132348
RW-excl spins 0, rounds 4549418, OS waits 46022
RW-sx spins 77387, rounds 2038061, OS waits 36655
Spin rounds per wait: 500842.00 RW-shared, 4549418.00 RW-excl, 26.34 RW-sx
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2019-05-13 11:33:38 0x7f23cda2a700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 349141353, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 8 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 3 row lock(s), undo log entries 50
MySQL thread id 366841, OS thread handle 139791774799616, query id 284015406 host1.example.com 1.2.3.4 confluence updating
update CONTENT set HIBERNATEVERSION=77, TITLE='GI-PIE -5/2019', LOWERTITLE='gi-pie -5/2019', VERSION=1, CREATOR='8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e130f90197', CREATIONDATE='2019-05-06 12:08:18', LASTMODIFIER='8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e13bb3104c', LASTMODDATE='2019-05-13 08:33:37.259', VERSIONCOMMENT='', PREVVER=236655373, CONTENT_STATUS='draft', PAGEID=null, SPACEID=71761978, CHILD_POSITION=null, PARENTID=null where CONTENTID=236655392 and HIBERNATEVERSION=76
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6031 page no 126359 n bits 152 index PRIMARY of table `confluencedatabase`.`CONTENT` trx id 349141353 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 40 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 29; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000e1b1320; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000014cf7478; asc     tx;;
 2: len 7; hex 70000006b7173e; asc p     >;;
 3: len 4; hex 50414745; asc PAGE;;
 4: len 14; hex 47492d504945202d352f32303139; asc GI-PIE -5/2019;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 6: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531333066393031; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e130f901; (total 32 bytes);
 7: len 5; hex 99a30cc212; asc      ;;
 8: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531336262333130; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e13bb310; (total 32 bytes);
 9: len 5; hex 99a31a8825; asc     %;;
 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 11: len 8; hex 800000000e1b130d; asc         ;;
 12: len 5; hex 6472616674; asc draft;;
 13: len 8; hex 800000000447003a; asc      G :;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: SQL NULL;
 18: SQL NULL;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: SQL NULL;
 21: SQL NULL;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: SQL NULL;
 24: SQL NULL;
 25: SQL NULL;
 26: SQL NULL;
 27: len 4; hex 8000004c; asc    L;;
 28: len 14; hex 67692d706965202d352f32303139; asc gi-pie -5/2019;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 349141355, ACTIVE 1 sec starting index read, thread declared inside InnoDB 5000
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
14 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 9 row lock(s), undo log entries 55
MySQL thread id 366887, OS thread handle 139791750571776, query id 284017007 host1.example.com 1.2.3.4 confluence updating
update CONTENT set HIBERNATEVERSION=77, TITLE='GI-PIE -5/2019', LOWERTITLE='gi-pie -5/2019', VERSION=1, CREATOR='8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e130f90197', CREATIONDATE='2019-05-06 12:08:18', LASTMODIFIER='8a888eb5604d391001606c8e8c390013', LASTMODDATE='2019-05-13 08:33:37.913', VERSIONCOMMENT='', PREVVER=236655373, CONTENT_STATUS='draft', PAGEID=null, SPACEID=71761978, CHILD_POSITION=null, PARENTID=null where CONTENTID=236655392 and HIBERNATEVERSION=76
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 6031 page no 126359 n bits 152 index PRIMARY of table `confluencedatabase`.`CONTENT` trx id 349141355 lock mode S locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 40 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 29; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000e1b1320; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000014cf7478; asc     tx;;
 2: len 7; hex 70000006b7173e; asc p     >;;
 3: len 4; hex 50414745; asc PAGE;;
 4: len 14; hex 47492d504945202d352f32303139; asc GI-PIE -5/2019;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 6: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531333066393031; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e130f901; (total 32 bytes);
 7: len 5; hex 99a30cc212; asc      ;;
 8: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531336262333130; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e13bb310; (total 32 bytes);
 9: len 5; hex 99a31a8825; asc     %;;
 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 11: len 8; hex 800000000e1b130d; asc         ;;
 12: len 5; hex 6472616674; asc draft;;
 13: len 8; hex 800000000447003a; asc      G :;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: SQL NULL;
 18: SQL NULL;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: SQL NULL;
 21: SQL NULL;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: SQL NULL;
 24: SQL NULL;
 25: SQL NULL;
 26: SQL NULL;
 27: len 4; hex 8000004c; asc    L;;
 28: len 14; hex 67692d706965202d352f32303139; asc gi-pie -5/2019;;

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 6031 page no 126359 n bits 152 index PRIMARY of table `confluencedatabase`.`CONTENT` trx id 349141355 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 40 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 29; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 8; hex 800000000e1b1320; asc         ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000014cf7478; asc     tx;;
 2: len 7; hex 70000006b7173e; asc p     >;;
 3: len 4; hex 50414745; asc PAGE;;
 4: len 14; hex 47492d504945202d352f32303139; asc GI-PIE -5/2019;;
 5: len 4; hex 80000001; asc     ;;
 6: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531333066393031; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e130f901; (total 32 bytes);
 7: len 5; hex 99a30cc212; asc      ;;
 8: len 30; hex 386138383865623534356434653065643031343564346531336262333130; asc 8a888eb545d4e0ed0145d4e13bb310; (total 32 bytes);
 9: len 5; hex 99a31a8825; asc     %;;
 10: len 0; hex ; asc ;;
 11: len 8; hex 800000000e1b130d; asc         ;;
 12: len 5; hex 6472616674; asc draft;;
 13: len 8; hex 800000000447003a; asc      G :;;
 14: SQL NULL;
 15: SQL NULL;
 16: SQL NULL;
 17: SQL NULL;
 18: SQL NULL;
 19: SQL NULL;
 20: SQL NULL;
 21: SQL NULL;
 22: SQL NULL;
 23: SQL NULL;
 24: SQL NULL;
 25: SQL NULL;
 26: SQL NULL;
 27: len 4; hex 8000004c; asc    L;;
 28: len 14; hex 67692d706965202d352f32303139; asc gi-pie -5/2019;;

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1)
------------
TRANSACTIONS
------------
Trx id counter 349167123
Purge done for trx's n:o < 349166996 undo n:o < 0 state: running but idle
History list length 60
LIST OF TRANSACTIONS FOR EACH SESSION:
---TRANSACTION 421321232847888, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232846976, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232845152, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232844240, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232842416, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232841504, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232837856, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232836032, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232816880, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232814144, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232835120, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232833296, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232831472, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232834208, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232832384, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232825088, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232826912, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232807760, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232828736, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232824176, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232830560, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232829648, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232815968, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232810496, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232818704, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232813232, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232815056, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232852448, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232840592, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232827824, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232820528, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232808672, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232848800, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 421321232843328, not started
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
---TRANSACTION 349167122, ACTIVE (PREPARED) 0 sec
2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s), undo log entries 1
MySQL thread id 368496, OS thread handle 139791782520576, query id 286235395 host1.example.com 1.2.3.4 confluence starting
commit
---TRANSACTION 349167115, ACTIVE 0 sec
0 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 0 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 368616, OS thread handle 139792195106560, query id 286235224 host1.example.com 1.2.3.4 confluence
--------
FILE I/O
--------
I/O thread 0 state: waiting for completed aio requests (insert buffer thread)
I/O thread 1 state: waiting for completed aio requests (log thread)
I/O thread 2 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 3 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 4 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 5 state: waiting for completed aio requests (read thread)
I/O thread 6 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 7 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 8 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
I/O thread 9 state: waiting for completed aio requests (write thread)
Pending normal aio reads: [0, 0, 0, 0] , aio writes: [0, 0, 0, 0] ,
 ibuf aio reads:, log i/o's:, sync i/o's:
Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0
777636 OS file reads, 7510119 OS file writes, 1623319 OS fsyncs
0.16 reads/s, 16384 avg bytes/read, 17.18 writes/s, 2.02 fsyncs/s
-------------------------------------
INSERT BUFFER AND ADAPTIVE HASH INDEX
-------------------------------------
Ibuf: size 1, free list len 1295, seg size 1297, 54874 merges
merged operations:
 insert 71353, delete mark 147192, delete 41416
discarded operations:
 insert 0, delete mark 0, delete 0
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 345 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 3503 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 2091 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 765 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 3178 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 2194 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 13262 buffer(s)
Hash table size 12748403, node heap has 628 buffer(s)
8461.44 hash searches/s, 986.45 non-hash searches/s
---
LOG
---
Log sequence number 11024428065319
Log flushed up to   11024428059196
Pages flushed up to 11024311886148
Last checkpoint at  11024311886148
0 pending log flushes, 0 pending chkp writes
2969484 log i/o's done, 12.92 log i/o's/second
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 52772732928
Dictionary memory allocated 1771678
Buffer pool size   3145344
Free buffers       2278005
Database pages     841373
Old database pages 310721
Modified db pages  24416
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 5090, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 777432, created 63941, written 4125089
0.16 reads/s, 0.20 creates/s, 4.10 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 841373, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
----------------------
INDIVIDUAL BUFFER POOL INFO
----------------------
---BUFFER POOL 0
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       284504
Database pages     105431
Old database pages 38934
Modified db pages  3151
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 661, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 96936, created 8495, written 787625
0.06 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 105431, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 1
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       284699
Database pages     105204
Old database pages 38854
Modified db pages  2623
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 657, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 97357, created 7847, written 127666
0.04 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 105204, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 2
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       285705
Database pages     104222
Old database pages 38492
Modified db pages  2920
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 679, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 97000, created 7222, written 383290
0.02 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 104222, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 3
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       286218
Database pages     103710
Old database pages 38302
Modified db pages  3227
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 633, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 96163, created 7547, written 853156
0.00 reads/s, 0.02 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 103710, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 4
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       286067
Database pages     103903
Old database pages 38373
Modified db pages  3133
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 606, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 96513, created 7390, written 620797
0.00 reads/s, 0.04 creates/s, 0.53 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 103903, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 5
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       283399
Database pages     106492
Old database pages 39330
Modified db pages  2871
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 640, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 98064, created 8428, written 480039
0.02 reads/s, 0.00 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 106492, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 6
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       284042
Database pages     105876
Old database pages 39092
Modified db pages  3346
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 546, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 97330, created 8546, written 538629
0.02 reads/s, 0.08 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 105876, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
---BUFFER POOL 7
Buffer pool size   393168
Free buffers       283371
Database pages     106535
Old database pages 39344
Modified db pages  3145
Pending reads      0
Pending writes: LRU 0, flush list 0, single page 0
Pages made young 668, not young 0
0.00 youngs/s, 0.00 non-youngs/s
Pages read 98069, created 8466, written 333887
0.00 reads/s, 0.02 creates/s, 0.51 writes/s
Buffer pool hit rate 1000 / 1000, young-making rate 0 / 1000 not 0 / 1000
Pages read ahead 0.00/s, evicted without access 0.00/s, Random read ahead 0.00/s
LRU len: 106535, unzip_LRU len: 0
I/O sum[0]:cur[0], unzip sum[0]:cur[0]
--------------
ROW OPERATIONS
--------------
7 queries inside InnoDB, 0 queries in queue
7 read views open inside InnoDB
Process ID=30983, Main thread ID=139792505267968, state: sleeping
Number of rows inserted 2342326, updated 2125054, deleted 690782, read 124274116335
7.49 inserts/s, 10.14 updates/s, 1.92 deletes/s, 1025472.01 reads/s
----------------------------
END OF INNODB MONITOR OUTPUT
============================
```

***EDIT**
Adding screenshot of resource usage. 5/7 is when the MySQL process was killed originally.
[image: MySQL VM Resource Usage]

Comment: The instance isn't usually "consuming a lot more CPU" by itself. Look at the query log to see what it is actually doing when CPU utilization is a problem, and address the underlying problem.

Comment: Nothing has changed on the application side. Prior to the MySQL kill/restart the resources on the VM weren't being taxed. The system stats all show the CPU usage increases during core business and it's all user CPU being used by the MySQL process. I'm looking for guidance on how to go about gathering and analyzing the data at the MySQL level. I can enable the slow query log, but I'm unsure how to analyze and even if I find a problem query this is a commercial app I have no access to modify SQLs on.

Comment: Just for clarification, I enabled the slow query log and have been watching for over an hour now. There have been 0 updates to the slow query log, yet the CPU usage still is high and maxing out.

Comment: You probably want general log. Only keep in mind that under heavy load it may become a notable resource consumer in itself.

Comment: After doing further research of the slow query log I was seeing a lot of selects taking in the 2-4 second range. A bug report on the vendor's site from a user says in MySQL 5.7 the optimizer switch `derived_merge` changed behavior. Changed that setting to off and now it appears CPU usage has drastically reduced and those queries are coming in subsecond now. Don't believe this was set to off before the restart, but unsure.